# Format check on date of birth in Python

Tags: python, database, sqlite, validation, tkinter

I am currently developing a database application, where the user fills out a customer form and the data is added to a SQLite3 table. I am trying to add validation to my code, and I have it working, however it adds the record to the table with the invalid data. Is there any way to stop the execution of the code if the data is invalid? See the code and a screenshot of the interface below:

```
    def validate(self):
        dateofbirth = self.DOBEntry.get()
        try:
            datetime.datetime.strptime(dateofbirth, '%D/%M/%Y')
        except ValueError:
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error","Please enter the date of birth in the correct format DD-MM-YYYY")



    def AddCustomer(self):
        customerid = int(self.CustomerEntry.get())
        branchid = self.BranchEntry.get()
        name = self.NameEntry.get()
        surname = self.SurnameEntry.get()
        dateofbirth = self.DOBEntry.get()
        town = self.TownEntry.get()
        postcode = self.PostcodeEntry.get()
        email = self.EmailEntry.get()
        telephone = self.TelephoneEntry.get()
        medical = self.MedicalEntry.get()
        try:
            self.validate()
            with sqlite3.connect("LeeOpt.db") as db:
                cursor = db.cursor()
                add_customer = ('''INSERT INTO Customer(CustomerID, BranchID, Name, Surname, DateOfBirth, Town, Postcode, EmailAddress, TelephoneNo, MedicalConditions)
                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''')
                cursor.execute(add_customer, [(customerid),(branchid),(name),(surname),(dateofbirth),(town),(postcode),(email),(telephone),(medical)])
                tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Notification","Customer added successfully")
                self.ClearEntries()
        except (sqlite3.IntegrityError): 
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error","This CustomerID is already taken, please try another.")
            self.ClearID()
```

[image: User Interface]

Comment: What is invalid data?

Comment: Just have `validate` return `True` or `False` and then check that value before updating the record. Or, have `validate` re-raise the exception after displaying the dialog.

Comment: @CoolCloud a date that does not meet the format set out in the function.

Comment: I think putting `self.validate` inside of `try` does no good, because no errors will be shown anyway because you skip the error within the function. So I think its best to return `True` or `False` from the function and check `if self.validate():` and then proceed.

Comment: @CoolCloud excuse my ignorance, I am a beginner with Python, how do return `True` or `False`?. I done a bit of research but cannot make an understanding of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
def validate(self):
    dateofbirth = self.DOBEntry.get()
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(dateofbirth, '%D/%M/%Y')
        return True # returns a boolean True
    except ValueError: 
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error","Please enter the date of birth in the correct format DD-MM-YYYY")
        return False

def AddCustomer(self):
    # Same code

    if self.validate(): # If true is returned, then...also same as if self.validate()==True
        try:
            with sqlite3.connect("LeeOpt.db") as db:
                cursor = db.cursor()
                add_customer = ('''INSERT INTO Customer(CustomerID, BranchID, Name, Surname, DateOfBirth, Town, Postcode, EmailAddress, TelephoneNo, MedicalConditions)
                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''')
                cursor.execute(add_customer, (customerid,branchid,name,surname,dateofbirth,town,postcode,email,telephone,medical))
                tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Notification","Customer added successfully")
                self.ClearEntries()
        except (sqlite3.IntegrityError): 
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error","This CustomerID is already taken, please try another.")
            self.ClearID()
```

Here `True` will be returned only if there is no error in the line, else `False` will be returned, so based on that, you make an `if` inside `AddCustomer()`. I also changed your parameters for `execute` onto a `tuple` rather than a `list` as it is convention.

Comment: I tried this, however, it keeps detecting an error and displaying the error message, even if the date format is input correctly.

Comment: @arthur_fleck The date error message? If that is coming, it means there is a `ValueError`, use `print(dateofbirth)` inside the function and make sure the data is what you expect it to be.